# Is there anything that can replace this part?: AP7333-33SRG-7

Tags: voltage-regulator, surface-mount

(It's my first experience in this field and it's my first question on this site, so please understand that my question is awkward.)

Part in question: mouser.com/ProductDetail/Diodes-Incorporated/AP7333-33SRG-7?qs=%2Fha2pyFadujyOKKgeO6pcGHmv%252Bb7mQpoOIrfChDRb0XNtjiw7EJcwA%3D%3D

As you can see from the link, it's out of stock now, and I wonder if there are other parts that can replace it.

Additional question: What is the difference between SOT-23R-3 and SOT-23-3?

Thanks.

Comment: The 23R is probably a different pinout from the 23. Think of it as a "reversed pinout" of some kind.

Comment: "SOT23" is a sloppily used term, there's all manner of different pinouts on them - manufacturers don't necessarily follow the standard.

Answer (score 1):

It's an LDO, many other manufacturers make those.

It doesn't appear to have any particularly 'very good' specifications, like low noise, low Iq, low dropout voltage, high accuracy, so should be fairly easy to replace. It is stable with ceramic capacitors, as are most post-2010 LDOs, but be warned that some earlier types are not.

Check the requirements of the design to see what specifications are important for the part, rather than trying to match all the specifications of the original part. This will open up many more parts as substitute options. As @Lundin's comment points out, you might not even need an LDO, a voltage reference might do.

You might need the -R 'reversed' pinout to fit a board you have, though *in extremis* you could almost certainly flip a standard package over and bend the leads down if you only had one or a few to fit.

[This Q/A](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/579604/parts-shortage-no-stock-what-now-canonical-reference-question) is related.

Comment: Depending on current needed (300mA in a SOT23 sounds like a lot of heat btw), it could perhaps also be replaced with various voltage reference parts. Which could either be some high accuracy LDOs or just a glorified zener diode in SOT23.